# Параллельное редактирование несколькими пользователями dbf таблицы через ADO соединение

Tags: delphi

Программирование на Delphi 7. Драйвер - ODBC. Несколько таблиц открывает приложение через ADO соединение. Таблицы связаны между собой через LookUp поля. Приложение размещается в локальной сети. `CursorLocation := clUseClient.` Несколько пользователей открывают приложение и редактируют одну и ту же таблицу одновременно (добавляют новые строки). У каждого возникает ошибка при процедуре "AdoTable.Post", что не удаётся найти строку и её содержимое могло быть изменено. Как быть? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй изменить тип блокировки на LockType := adLockOptymistic (при использовании транзакций выставляется пессимистическая блокировка). Также, есть еще один ньюанс (по крайней мере для Access) - способ открытия базы данных - требуется открывать в режиме общего доступа для чтения-записи.

Comment: У меня были таблицы с LockType:=LTOptimistic - возникали точно такие же ошибки при заполнении таблиц новыми строками и удалением старых даже при работе строго одного пользователя. Может быть из-за индексов таблиц ?.  Попробую, спасибо.